# Why does this code that checks what input the user puts not work properly?

Tags: python-2.x

When I ask the user what object they'd like to use the program ignores the elif statement.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random

#Variables

name = raw_input
answer = raw_input
objectList = ['coin', 'piece of paper', 'bundle of sticks']

#Game code

def game():
    name = raw_input("What is your name?: ")
    print ('-----------------------------------------------------------------')
    print ('Hello, ' +  str(name) + ', you tripped into a hole and fell unconcious')
    print ('to wake up in a dungeon. There is a door in front of you, but it ')
    print ('seems to be locked.')
    print ("\n")
    print ('Look around for a tool?')
    askForObject()


#answer for question
def askForObject():
    if "yes" in answer():
        print('-----------------------------------------------------------------')
        print('There are two objects on the ground; a mysterious contraption with')
        print('two prongs, and a ' + random.choice(objectList) + '.')
        print("\n")
        print('Which tool will you pick up? The contraption or the object?')
        pickUpPrompt()               
    else:
        print('What do you mean? Yes, or no?')
        askForObject()

        #ask the user what tool they will pick up
def pickUpPrompt():
    if 'object' in answer():
        print('You picked up the object, but it has no apparent use on the door')
        print('Try again')
        pickUpPrompt()
    elif 'contraption' in answer():
            print('You picked up the contraption.')
            doorPrompt()    
    else:
        print('What object are you talking about?')
        pickUpPrompt()
def doorPrompt():
    print ('-----------------------------------------------------------------')
    print ('Will you use the contraption on the door?')
    if 'yes' in answer():
        print ('door')

game()
```

I've tried using different operators instead but I've run into problems with how the string is called. It seems to work if you input the same answer twice but I don't know why that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elif isn't working properly because it calls the raw_input a second time. That's why entering the same answer twice works, because the second entry matches the elif condition. What you could do is call raw_input in the first line of pickUpPrompt and save it as a variable, then use the if/elif/else.

```
def pickUpPrompt():
    ans = answer()
    if 'object' in ans:
        print('You picked up the object, but it has no apparent use on the door')
        print('Try again')
        pickUpPrompt()
    elif 'contraption' in ans:
            print('You picked up the contraption.')
            doorPrompt()    
    else:
        print('What object are you talking about?')
        pickUpPrompt()
```